# Java - Compare-and-swap over a static field

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, compare-and-swap

I was wondering if there was any way to perform a compare-and-swap operation on static fields in Java, using `Unsafe`, more precisely `compareAndSwapObject`. I attempted using `null` and the class object (`TheClass.class`) as a first argument, but it didn't work.

Edit:
Here's the code:

```java
public class UnsafeTest
{
 
    public static long staticField = 0;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Long l = 0L;
        Long res = 350L;
        Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);
        long off = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(
                UnsafeTest.class.getDeclaredField("staticField"));
        unsafe.compareAndSwapObject(UnsafeTest.class, off, l, res);

        // null instead of UnsafeTest.class produces the same result
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        System.out.println(staticField); // prints 0
    }

}
```

I wanted it to perform a CAS on the field `staticField`, setting it to 350 (arbitrary value). What happened: when printing its value on the standard output, it displayed 0; so I suppose that nothing changed and that neither of those is the correct argument to do what I want to, assuming it is possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you are using `compareAndSwapObject` on a field that is not a reference type.  Since the field is a `long`, you should be using `compareAndSwapLong`.

Also, the `compareAndSwapXXX` methods return a `boolean` to say if the swap succeeded or failed.  You should check it ... if there is any possibility that some other thread might do a CAS operation on the same field.  (And if there is no possibility, don't bother with CAS.  Just use regular assignments.)

Finally, I looked at the Java 8 source code, and I don't think that the `Unsafe.compareAndSwapXxx` operations are designed to work on `static` fields using a `Class` object as the target object.   Instead, I think you need to do something like this:

```
    Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);
    long off = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(
            UnsafeTest.class.getDeclaredField("staticField"));
    Object target = unsafe.staticFieldBase(f);
    unsafe.compareAndSwapLong(target, off, 0L, 350L);
```

Either way, there is no checking that the `off` value is correct for the field of the object that you do the CAS operation on.  So if you get it wrong, you are liable to get memory corruption (and incorrect results or a JVM crash) ... rather than a nice clean Java exception.  This is the risk you take by using `Unsafe`!

---

Having said all of the above, any code that uses `Unsafe` code will be non-portable.  And your code will fail for Java 9 and later because the `compareAndSwapXxx` methods have been removed.

The correct way to do this in Java 9 and later will be to use the `VarHandle` class; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html).

Comment: The worst thing about memory corruption is not the potential JVM crash. The worst thing that can happen, is the application continuing with wrong but plausible data.